# JPA not automatically populating both foreign keys in a child entity using @JoinColumns

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student_info")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class StudentInfo implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "request_uuid", nullable = false, length = 30)
  private String requestUuid;

  @Column(name = "student_uuid", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 13)
  private String studentUuid;


  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "student_uuid", referencedColumnName = "student_uuid")
  private List<StudentAcceptances> acceptances;


}
```

In `StudentAcceptances`, there isn't a reference for `student_uuid` because JPA automatically inserts the data for `student_uuid`.

However, now I've tried to use two foreign keys: `studentUuid` and `requestUuid`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student_info")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class StudentInfo implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "request_uuid", nullable = false, length = 30)
  private String requestUuid;

  @Column(name = "student_uuid", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 13)
  private String studentUuid;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name = "student_uuid", referencedColumnName = "student_uuid"),
      @JoinColumn(name = "request_uuid", referencedColumnName = "request_uuid")
  })
  private List<StudentAcceptances> acceptances;
}
```

With this configuration, JPA doesn't automatically insert the data for `request_uuid`.

What I'm aiming for here is: when I fetch `StudentInfo` based on `requestUuid` and `student_uuid`, the corresponding filtering should also apply to the child entity `StudentAcceptances`.

Comment: You've got "request_uuid" double mapped - once as a foreign key and again as a basic mapping. You should set one as read-only (insertable=false, updatable=false), likely the @Column(name = "request_uuid" mapping in the StudentInfo if you want the `List<StudentAcceptances> acceptances` mapping to be setting that column instead of your entity. Same goes for the "student_uuid" which is also double mapped, but you've likely been more careful and set the same "student_uuid" value in all 3 entities manually. You might want to look into bidirectional OneToMany relationships to let JPA manage that

Comment: @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name = "student_uuid", referencedColumnName = "student_uuid", insertable = false, updatable = false),
      @JoinColumn(name = "request_uuid", referencedColumnName = "request_uuid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  }) So you suggest OneToMany bidirectional?

Comment: In general, yes, but maybe not here. My first response was mistaken as I misread your model and problem; it could be that request_uuid is double mapped (with a basic mapping in StudentAcceptances) but you'd have to show the entity to see the problem. FKs in unidirectional OneToMany are controlled by the StudentInfo entity, so the StudentAcceptances rows may not be inserted/updated with StudentAcceptances entity changes, but after the fact in a separate statement. If you have the FK controlled within StudentAcceptances (a writable basic mapping or ManyToOne), it can make things easier